# Hydra says different passwords with are correct each run, but only one works

Tags: authentication, brute-force, hydra, ctf

I am doing CTF 'Skynet' from THM and came across this problem.
Enumerating SMB, I gathered credentials 'milesdyson' and a list of passwords 'log1.txt'.
I figured that I could try to brute force squirrelMail login form using Hydra. This is the POST request by Burpsuite.[image]

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tJgPyRITGc), I could use the following syntax: `<url>:<form parameters>:<condition string> [:<optional> [:<optional>]]` to perform a brute force attempt through Hydra. It also explained that the last part(condition string) regards a trigger to indicate success or failure in my request.

I saw that the server response to my request is "Unknown user or password incorrect."

Could I add the word "incorrect" as the condition, or is the whole sentence "Unknown user or password incorrect." better?

This is my attempt:

```
hydra -l milesdyson -P /root/log1.txt  http-post-form://10.10.6.90/squirrelmail/src/login.php:"login_username=^USER^&secretkey=^PASS^":"incorrect" -F -I -V
```

What I noticed is that by executing the same command, I get different solutions each time (the correct solution is `cyborg007haloterminator` which is seen sometimes, but not always). Why is hydra concluding that these other passwords with `terminator` in them are correct? If I try any of them, I get the "Unknown user or password incorrect." message.

[image]

Comment: Here's another test: log in 16 times with wrong passwords. Does the message change?

Comment: @schroeder I have tried login 16 times and message does not change